# Strange iPhone5 letterboxing

Tags: ios, xcode

I have just installed Xcode 4.6.3 to test my OpenGL game (which was developed in Xcode 3)  on Retina 4" simulator, and I have got two black bars on the screen's top and bottom.

I have added a Default-568h@2x.png image file with dimension of 640x1136 to my project, when I am testing on the iphone simulator, the Default image is displayed correctly with no bars at all, but once the game starts, the top bar is moved to the bottom of the screen, now I have a sum of two bars at the bottom and no bar at all at the top.

I have done some google search but it seems no one had the same problem before, I am getting this result on the iPhone simulator and have got no iphone5 to confirm this would happen in real device...

I would really appreciate someone could help on this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and the solution I found was to stop using the asset catalog for the Launch Images. That allowed it to revert to using the properly named files it was looking for.